# Upload multi files controls?

Tags: 2010, file-upload

I have a web part which contains FileUpload asp.net control , i want to replace FileUpload asp.net control with Upload Multi Files Sharepoint control.

Is there a way to reference this control in my project?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Multi Files UploadControl (UploadCtl) is a Activex Control defined in the STSUPLD.dll, which in turn gets installed during the Microsoft Office 2010 setup (refer to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms456628.aspx) for more info)

You can use the object in your webpart:

```
<OBJECT id=idUploadCtl name=idUploadCtl CLASSID=CLSID:07B06095-5687-4d13-9E32-12B4259C9813 WIDTH='100%' HEIGHT='350px'></OBJECT>
```

and, some hidden fields to config the control

```
    <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME="PostURL" id=PostURL VALUE="the page recive the files you upload" />        
    <INPUT TYPE=hidden NAME="Confirmation-URL" id="Confirmation-URL" VALUE="after upload the control will redriect to this url." />
    <INPUT type=hidden name="putopts" id=putopts value="true">
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="VTI-GROUP" VALUE="0">
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="Cmd" VALUE="Save">
```